# update table with limit and offset in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

hi is it possible to update a table with values form an other table with limit and offset?

for example the table t_device has 600 rows
and t_object has 100 rows

i want to update a column but only the first 100 rows with an offset from a subquery  like

```
update t_device set id_object = 
(select id_object from t_object limit 100) limit 100 offset 0;

update t_device set id_object = 
(select id_object from t_object limit 100) limit 100 offset 100;
```

is it possible? i cant find a solution to modive the value in t_device from t_object

im using postgres 8.4

Answer (score 9):

- That UPDATE statement doesn't look like it is going to be much use if you are just setting id_object to id_object, albeit in a semi-random order.
- If there is no unique WHERE predicate in the t_device table UPDATE statement, there is no guarantee that only 100 rows will be updated, which is what I assume the intent of the outer LIMIT is.
- You should have an ORDER BY in the subquery to ensure you are not getting overlaps in rows.

Something like the following might work for you.

```
UPDATE t_device set id_object = t.id_object
FROM (select id_object from t_object order by id_object limit 100) t
WHERE t.id_object = t_device.id_object;
```

Comment: with "WHERE t.id_object = t_device.id_object;" i update 0 rows because they have no relation i just need to update always 100 rows in t_device with offsets 0, 100, 200 etc with the values from t_object ordered by id (in this table der are only 103 rows and in device 600)

Answer (score 1):

i solved it with generating a column rowNumber and and updated it with incremental values (1, 2, 3)

and then

```
UPDATE t_device set id_object = t.id_object FROM 
(select t1.id_object , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_object ) AS rn
from  dblink('dbname=*** password=***', 'select id_object from t_object') 
as t1(id_object int) order by id_object limit 103) as t
where t_device.rowNumber = t.rn
```